# spring boot oauth2 roles filter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-config

I'm using spring-cloud-security and @EnableOAuth2Sso in a spring config server to configure oauth2. After my oauth provider authenticates the user, I want to validate that the user has the correct role.  My first thought is that I need to add a filter that runs after the oAuth authentication.  Do I need to extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and add a filter?  If so could you provide sample code of how to do it?  I've done some searching trying to piece this together, but have not had any success.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for roles during authentication and to achieve that you can write a custom implementation of `UserDetailsService`. This is called during authentication by `DaoAuthenticationProvider` to load user details.

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    final AbstractUser user = Optional.ofNullable((AbstractUser) userRepository.findUserByUsername(username)).orElseGet(() -> userTempRepository.findUserByUsername(username));

    if (Objects.isNull(user)) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("Username \'%s\' not found.", username));
    }

    final boolean accountNonLocked = USER_STATUS_ACTIVE.equalsIgnoreCase(user.getStatus());

    final List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = user.getRoles() == null
                                                      ? Collections.emptyList()
                                                      : user.getRoles().stream()
                                                            .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());


    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), true, true,
                                                                  true, accountNonLocked, grantedAuthorities);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the authoritiesExtractor method as described in [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) tutorial.  That gave me access to the oAuth information returned and allowed me to check that the user is in the correct role.  This appears to be doing what I need.

I would have liked to implement this in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure` with `hasAnyRole`, but I could not figure out how to do that.